# google map, winform and catching click events

Tags: winforms, google-maps, double-click

I am having a scenario where I have to read some data from database eg addresses that already have latitude and longitude infos and then populate the google map with markers. I am using Google map with Windows form and winform web browser control.

The brower control is showing a .asp page where the details of the addresses are passed using query string.

The requirement is that if the user is clicking any of these markers in the google map then we should capture the click event and process the result eg get the ID of the address and maybe navigate to specific record in windows form.

The question is how can I capture the click event and then pass the data from .asp page to windows form?

Any other better possibilities? suggestions?